# Is it possible to trigger an image download from push notification when the app is closed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, push-notification, background-image

I'm developing a messaging app (something like WhatsApp), users can send text and image messages to one another.

Currently if user1 sends an image message to user2, while user2 is offline (the app is closed) -> my server will detect that user2 is offline -> and will send him a push notification about the new image.

Then when user2 open the app, the image is downloaded and presented to him in the chat view.

The problem with this is that user2 gets a push about new image -> open the app to see that image -> but then needs to wait until the image is downloaded...
So this is not the best user experience, I want that when user2 open the app he will see the image **immediately**!

The only thing I can think of is to wake up the app with the push notification and start downloading the image even if user2 didn't open the app yet, but I don't know if this is possible?
Or any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately when your app is in an inactive state you cannot respond to a notification until the user chooses to re-launch it.

Comment: The only exception to this is Newsstand apps, which may actually initiate preemptive downloading upon receiving a push notification. This behavior can only be achieved once a day per app, however.

Comment: So how does the iPhone messaging app present a push with the image?

Comment: Apps made by Apple don't have to follow the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Using Push Notifications to Initiate a Download
If your server sends push notifications to a user’s device when new content is available for your app, you can ask the system to run your app in the background so that it can begin downloading the new content right away.

[Click here to Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW57)

Enjoy :)

Comment: Even when the app is totally closed off?